# Formated string js jumps out of defined area

Tags: javascript, html, string, image, fetch-api

I am fetching from our backend an jpg encoded via Base64.
After this i want to insert it into the website.

```
        partypicture = await res3.text();
        partyimage.innerHTML = `<img src="${partypicture}" class="test">`;
```

In the HTML I am now expecting something like:

```
       <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/2wBDAAoHBwgHBgoICAgLCgoLDhgQA(etc)" class="test">;
```

But on the website the picture can't be loaded because the img looks like this:

```
<img src="" data:image="" jpeg;base64,="" 9j="" 2wbdaaohbwghbgoicaglcgoldhgqdg0ndh0vfheyix8ljcifiiemkzcvjik0kseimeexndk7pj4+js5esum8sdc9pjv="" 2wbdaqolcw4ndhwqebw7ieaqoaaaaaakqauebrqqoaaaaab="" 9k="" class="test">
```

Although I am inserting the String into the src it is inserted after this.
I don't have any idea why this is happening.
In addition slashes in the base 64 are converted to :

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: `console.log(partypicture)`

Comment: data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/2wBDAAoHBwgHBgoICAgLCgoLDhgQA(etc) This is was I got via the console